# Work with network in swing application

Tags: java, swing, networking, thread-safety

I am developing swing application that will communicate with server via 
web sockets.

I plan to create separate threads for sending/receiving packets, connecting 
and disconnecting operations. Also for packet processing i plan to use queue.

Could you suggest, is this correct network layer design? 
Or there is exist something better?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say something on this subject, it really depends.

If you have experience with Rich Internet Applications you can design your application in a similar way. So, you could have a web service running SOAP and you Swing application exchanging data via asynchronous HTTP calls (similar to Ajax's approach).

Also, I would highly suggest designing some sort of MVC before getting started where the View would be your Swing components, the Controller would handle business rules/validations/threads, and the Model  handles the communication between your desktop app and web server.

Finally, I would discourage queueing packages. I did it in the past and regretted because it became too complex and convoluted. In my case, I realized that if something goes wrong I would just throw Exception and handle the error. So, in some cases it would result in a error message on the user interface where the user could take contingency actions; in other cases, the application would try that same operation again latter.

I hope this description can help you somehow.

Cheers,

Comment: But if without queue for packages - what happens if application didn't process previous package and arrived new one?

Comment: You are talking about networking packages, right? It should be a concern, you HTTP client should be able to handle it smoothly. By the way, I would suggest using: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga

Comment: **Correction** Should not be a concern...

Comment: Is it supports web socket? I don't such option.

Comment: Is mandatory for you to write using pure networking sockets? If yes, then if you to create your own approach to handle package queuing. If not, I highly recommend writing an web app and communicate via HTTP (maybe with Web Services, or pure HTTP calls, it is up to you). The second option will make your life a lot easier. Either way, everything I mentioned before still valid. Cheers